# Is there any creative way to populate html directly from a URL?

Tags: html, css

I am *not* trying to avoid using code (JS etc) here, but to *build* a certain tool.

Say I have a url string like `domain.com/somthing`, and this URL can return  a **single string** like "John", or maybe a JSON, according to my design.

Is there any way today using html/CSS **alone**, to populate html elements, using the respond from this url **directly** without code?

This for example is not possible: `<input value='domain.com/somthing' type="text">` even if the url will return a pure string like `"John"`.

Is this maybe possible using CSS or developers must use code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `iframe` element can display another resource embedded in the current page.

```
<iframe src="//example.com/"></iframe>
```

… but there is no HTML or CSS mechanism for setting an attribute value on an arbitrary element using a URL. You would need JS for that (e.g. [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) + [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents)).

Comment: thanks, so today html/css developers that don't know how to code for example, what tools can they use to populate html with very simple jsons? is there a simple way for them to do so still avoiding coding?

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). (Not that I know of one anyway, nor can I imagine anyone investing the effort in building a tool to do something that is trivial in any specific case, but is pretty hard to generalise, and rarely desired).

Comment: that was a comment not a question. I am not sure it is trivial for non coders to use JS for something so basic like adding key/value strings to their html